# Why is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2 k) !}=\left.\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2 k) !} x^{2 k}-1\right)\right|_{x=1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

In order to sum up the series we have to realize that it is almost the expansion of the cosine function. But we need $k=0$ in the sum. I don't know how to do this. The solution is   $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2 k) !}=\left.\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2 k) !} x^{2 k}-1\right)\right|_{x=1}$, but where does $-1$ on the right hand side come from and how did we achieve $k=0$?

My approach was to do the following, which leads to a dead end...(right?)

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2 k) !}=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2 k) !}=\cdots$

Comment: On the left you sum from $k=1$, and on the right from $k=0$, that's where the $-1$ comes from, don't you agree? Because $(-1)^0/(0!)=1$

Comment: Thank you, I think it makes sense. If we summed from $k=2$ then on the right with $k=0$ we would subtract $1/2$ right? so it would be $-1+1/2=-1/2$, did I understand this correctly?

Comment: yes, that's right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a convergent series $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k,$$

hence

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k-a_0.$$

Comment: This cleared up a lot in my mind, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @Chaos & @Fred said, it's because of first term added to right hand side ($k=0$). Also notice the benefit of relation:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}x^{2k} \Longrightarrow
f''(x) = -f(x) \Longrightarrow f(x) = a \sin (x) + b \cos (x)$$

May this is the purpose of relation.